# Android Manifest Merger failed, says android:exported is required, but I already have it

Tags: android, manifest

As the title says, my android test build is failing with the error "Manifest merger failed". It says "android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for "

The problem is, I already have android:exported set. Does anyone know what I can do here?

I have tried adding android:exported="true" to every one of my activities, but that had no affect.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the app runs and builds without issue normally. I only get this error when trying run Instrumented Tests

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fyp.launcher">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Home"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_AllApps"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.Activity_Settings"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.Activity_Theme"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.Activity_Favourites"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.Activity_Font"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please include the build output in your question rather than an abbreviated summary so we have a better chance at assisting you.

Comment: hi VectorsAreCool123, if you have libraries added in your project, add exported tag in them also.